# Orientation of multiplying integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Consider,

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$$

The trick is to multiply by $I$ again to get $I^2$ But they often write:

$$I^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 - y^2} dy\space dx$$

The issue is orientation.

$I$ is an integral, which is orientated in the $xy$ plane, and $x$ is the independent variable, y is the dependent variable.

When you consider the other one with $e^{-y^2}$, then $y$ is the independent variable and $x$ is the dependent variable.

How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to think of $x$ and $y$ as two independent variables, and something else, say $z$, would be the dependent variable.

In the first integral, if you're thinking of $y$ as the dependent variable, rename it as $z$, and then add $y$ as a second independent variable.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, a question is. But why are you replacing $x$ with $y$? When the $I^2 = I*I$ and $I$ has only $x$ terms.

Comment: Well, you need two different names for two different variables. You can't do an iterated integral where it's "$dx$" both times, so we need two names. Since the name of the variable doesn't matter, we call it $x$ for one integral and $y$ for the other. If you want to keep $y$ as your dependent variable, you could set up the integral as "$dx\,dt$" or something.

Comment: but $e^{-y^2}$ is **very different** from $e^{-x^2}$

Comment: How so? Relabel the variable, and it's the same function. Graph $z=e^{-y^2}$ and $z=e^{-x^2}$. You'll draw the same graph, twice.

Comment: So you are saying $x = y$?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying that a function is what it is, independent of what you decide to name the variable. If I say $f(x)=x^2$, or if I say $f(y)=y^2$, I'm defining precisely the same $f$. The variable $x$ or $y$ is just a placeholder. If I need two placeholders, I can use them both.

Comment: Ok. I sort of see what you mean. You are consider $x$ and $y$ in relation to $z$, so that $x$ and $y$ are both the **HORIZONTAL** axes in the plane?

Comment: Yes, that works. If you graph it as a function of two variables, you can think of the $xy$-plane as horizontal, and the $z$-axis as vertical.

Comment: In this way, $y$ is horizontal with respect to $z$ (as independent) but at the same time, $y$ is vertical with respect to $x$ (as dependent variable for $x$)?? Is this the idea??? Thanks

Comment: Actually, I'm not thinking of $y$ as the dependent variable for $x$ at all. It's just another independent variable, oriented perpendicularly to $x$. The only dependent variable is $z$. You're welcome!

Comment: That is impossible. If $z = e^{-x^2}$ and $z = e^{-x^2}$ then it is both the vertical axis to the x-plane, and the vertical axis to the y-plane which cant be true.

Comment: Sure it can. Imagine the usual $xy$-plane flat on the tabletop, and imagine the $z$ axis rising up vertically from the origin. It's vertical, and both the $x$- and $y$-axes are horizontal.

Comment: I see, but at the same time, doesnt the same relation hold for $y$ to $x$?

Comment: They are perpendicular, but if you're thinking of the function $z=e^{-x^2-y^2}$, then you don't get a graph in the $xy$-plane like you would if you graphed $y=e^{-x^2}$. You'll get two copies of that graph: one in the $xz$-plane, and one in the $yz$-plane.

Comment: I almost understand it. The only regard is, why wont it work if you consider $y$ as a dependent variable for $x$? Mostly, how is $z = e^{-y^2}$ equivalent to $z = e^{-x^2}$? They take on different values.

Comment: Here: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29+%3De%5E%28-y%5E2%29&x=0&y=0

And:

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29+%3De%5E%28-x%5E2%29+plot&x=0&y=0

Comment: I think I see where the confusion is. We're dealing with two completely different functions here. One is a function of one variable and it sends an input, say $t$, to the output $e^{-t^2}$. We could call the output $s$, and we would have $s=e^{-t^2}$. The second function takes two inputs, call them $u$ and $v$, and gives us an output, say $w$, according to the formula $w=e^{-u^2-v^2}$. Your initial integral is an integral of $s$ with respect to $t$. The second integral is an integral of $w$ with respect to $u$ and $v$.

Comment: What makes it confusing is that the names $x$ and $y$ are being used for different things. In your first integral, you're using $x$ and $y$ to refer to what I'm now calling $t$ and $s$. In the second integral, you're using $x$ and $y$ to refer to what I'm now calling $u$ and $v$. The dependent variable $s$ depends on the independent variable $t$, and the dependent variable $w$ depends on the independent variables $u$ and $v$. The connection between the two functions is that, if you set $u$ or $v$ equal to zero, rename the other as $t$, and rename $w$ as $s$, then you'll get the first function.

Answer (score -1):

Just an other solution (if you are interested by it):

We know that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx=1$$
(it's the normal law), therefore, if you set $u=\sqrt{2}x$, you get

$$1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-u^2}du\implies \int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: I am not the downvoter, this is a great answer, I cannot vote because i am not registered.