# What allows change of variables?

Tags: calculus, integration

In school, especscially, one is not taught "why" we can change variables, dummy variables in integration.

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

We can change the $x$ variable to $y$ for example.

The **idea is that the value of the expression does not depend on the given variable correct?**

This is known as the **bound variable** idea.

But how do we know that: *the value of the expression does not depend on the given variable*

??

Is it an axiom, theorem?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: A lot of people gave to you enough answers to understand the idea of variables in a integral, but you continue to ask the same thing. You asked that in: $$$$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091925/how-do-dummy-variables-work   $$$$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096728/definition-of-bound-free-variables $$$$http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091859/orientation-of-multiplying-integrals $$$$http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095250/replacing-variables-in-integration

Comment: Oh, I was thinking this question looked very familiar...

Comment: @AlexSilva, yup. I see that. But now I am asking **why** the **expression DOESNT change** rather than an acceptable fact

Comment: It was answered: "because the definite integral is a number!". Notice that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(\blacksquare) d\blacksquare = \int_{a}^{b}f(\spadesuit) d \spadesuit = \cdots$

Comment: How though? That is what I am asking. Is it from definition of bound variable?

Comment: @anonymous It seems to me that you're merely trolling. You're beginning to lose credibility around here.

Comment: @anonymous, your question is not important at all. It is the same to ask: why the number "ten" has two digits? Why to ask that? I'm beginning to believe that you're trolling us!

Comment: @anonymous: Just checking if you read my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095250/replacing-variables-in-integration). It seems you're trying to attach specific letters to specific mathematical concepts. But that's not exactly how mathematical notation works; particularly, it's not how "dummy" variables work. A separate point is, integrals can be written _without using variable names at all_, so your question is akin to, "Why doesn't '2' depend on x?'" (Added in edit: Siminore's answer makes exactly this point.)

Answer (score 4):

Another quick answer: get out of the 19th century! Functions are not $f$ of $x$. Functions are **independent** of the names of their variables. The following represent the **same** function:
$$
\begin{align}
x &\mapsto f(x) \\
t &\mapsto f(t) \\
u &\mapsto f(u) \\
\spadesuit &\mapsto f(\spadesuit) \\
\# &\mapsto f(\#)
\end{align}
$$
By contruction, the Riemann integral of a function depends only on the function (and on the interval $[a,b]$, but we do not take care of it now): therefore the notation $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$ is not only heavy, but also misleading. We should write it $\int_a^b f$.

Comment: Exactly, but math isnt a myth, (passed from generations) there has to be a reason why the value doesnt change.

Comment: The value does not change because there is **NO** $x$ variable at all!

Comment: Then what is the independent variable?

Comment: "Independent variable" is a notion that applies to particular _applications_ of functions. In the integral, _if_ we use the $dx$ notation at all (although as shown in this answer, we don't have to!), it signifies that $f$ is (in effect) evaluated at each point in the interval $(a,b).$

Comment: @DavidK, but overall, is this from the bound variable **definition**?

Comment: @anonymous It's from the definition of integration.

Comment: @DavidK, why not the bound variable definition?

Comment: Actually, is this simply substitutions such as $x=y$?

Comment: @anonymous People were using the $\int\ldots dx$ notation for integrals with very nearly the same meaning it has today for centuries before anyone had even thought to define "bound variable." But now we have such a definition and $x$ fits it, so it is convenient to use that term to describe $x$ (including describing the fact that we can do a simple substitution of some other symbol for $x$).

Comment: @DavidK I think I am almost there. We describe a variable, a variable is a placeholder? Is that from definition?

Comment: @DavidK, I see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html  that a dummy variable is a variable which  has no significance in the output

Answer (score 1):

This really harkens to computer science. When you do write a sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k,$$
the variable $k$ is a "loop variable;" to wit, it is a placeholder.  The sum sums the numbers in the list $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}$ regardless of the name of the variable used to index the sum.

The variable $k$ has a scope confined to the summation. The same is true for variables of integration.  In the integral
$$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx,$$
the variable $x$ is merely a placeholder.

You do a similar thing when do make a definition like this one
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x}, \qquad x \ge 0.$$
You can replace $x$ with cow as follows
$$f(\text{cow}) = \sqrt{\text{cow}}, \qquad \text{cow} \ge 0.$$
and the definition is unaltered.

Comment: But why doesnt this change the value

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing like an axiom, it as the same meaning and you are just changing a name.

For example, let's say we have :
$$a = b + c$$
Now, let $d = b$ and $e = c$. You have :
$$a = d + e$$

Comment: Not possible. Because then you cant solve the Gaussian Integral using $x = y$

Comment: Yet it's what happens.

Comment: Then try to solve the Gaussian Integral with the double integral method, you wont be able to.

Comment: You are changing the problem, here we are talking of a one variable. If you want to ask something about multivariable calculus, you must specify your question, and this on another post.

Comment: $(+1)$ the part I dont get it, is this **Because $x$ is a bound variable?**

Answer (score 0):

Put very simply, $x$ here in your example is a bound variable, before it was formed into an integrand it was a free variable. The integral sign is a variable-binding operator. We are free to change bound variables into other bound variables providing of course any labelling of the bound variable to the variable-binding operator is also suitabley changed.

Comment: By definition??

Answer (score 0):

It does not follow from what is usually considered an "axiom".

Indeed, it is an application of a general [rule of inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference_rules), called [Instantiation of universals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantiation_of_universals).

If you have time to spend on things like this, try follow and understand all the links in that Wikipedia page.